# Add child block with ajax rendered block in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have rendered sign up form with ajax. Following are the function which rendered the sign up form,

```
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register')
            ->setTemplate('Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml')
            //->toHtml()
                    ;
```

But with this other attribute which is created from admin, does not displaying on form.
So to display additional filed , I have updated above code with following code,

```
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register')
            ->setTemplate('Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes::/customer/form/register.phtml')
            //->toHtml()
                    ;
```

But still attributes does not displaying,Can any one have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by adding update handle.

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
        try {
            $resultPage=$resultPage->addHandle('customer_form_template_handle');
            $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register')
            ->setTemplate('Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes::/customer/form/register.phtml')
            ;

            $block_attr  = $resultPage->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block\Form')
                    ->setTemplate('Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes::form/userattributes.phtml')
                    ->setFormCode('customer_account_create')
                    ->setEntityModelClass('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
                    ;
            $block->setChild('customer_form_user_attributes',$block_attr);
            return $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $response = $e->getMessage();
            return $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
        }
    }
```